# the emails sent from my email accounts on my domain reach spam

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, whm

I have a small problem with a domain and that is that emails arrive to Spam and that the domain is new. I have checked the reputation of that domain and it has nothing out of the ordinary.

**Information**

I purchased a `CLOUD VPS` that runs `CLOUDLINUX` with static ips in a different provider than the one I acquired the domain. and I use `WHM` to manage my accounts. the emails are sent correctly, but they reach me in the SPAM tray. as additional information I just tried to send an email from the webmail tool offered by `CPANEL` from my account, and from here if they reach me in the inbox, but if I send from any email client like: (`Outlook`, `Thunderbird`) always I get to SPAM.
What could be the problem ?, Where should I start to review? Any help or collaboration is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your server's IP is listed in any RBL

This is a good tool for consult in multiples RBL: http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check

2. See if your reverse DNS or PTR is properly configured
3. In your apllication always send email by authenticating with SMTP.